# Upload PHP folder to FTP without Wordpress overriding routes

Tags: wordpress, url

How can I upload a folder like a regular site and place it within a Wordpress folder but not have wordpress override the URLs for that particular folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really *how* you can do this, but *why do it?*

WordPress is overriding your URLs because of its own permalinks and rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` that handles the folder Wordpress is installed in and all subdirectories. Read https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

In order to place a "regular" site within a WordPress folder, you're going to have to work out some complex regex expressions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex and integrate them into Wordpress's own rewrite rules so both sites work. And then, when you change WordPress's own permalinks from admin and WordPress writes changes to `.htaccess` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess, your own custom rules won't function anymore.

Directories below a directory with an `.htaccess` file will inherit those rewrite directives, so you can "negate" rewrite rules by putting a blank `.htaccess` file - or one with your own rules in it - in that folder. And this directory inheriting method is further controlled by server directives, if you have access to Apache `httpd`; which you won't, unless you're running your own server.

Again, why make things so complex? If you're going to use WordPress, integrate your content and site into WordPress. It is straightforward to integrate your own PHP and MySQL data into a WordPress site through the use of page templates. If you want a plain PHP/MySQL site in the same hosting area as WordPress, keep it separate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have decided to integrate it all into Wordpress instead of writing RegEx expressions.

Comment: I think that's the best way to go, too.